# Can't access request data in Node JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have an issue. Where when I send data using new FormData().

I can see the data in nodeJS in const payload = req.body;

here when I debug I see the payload have the object with key value pairs that I sent, but when I access for example payload.message, I get undefined for some reason

Also, when I tried to send request from postman instead of my react app it worked.

Here is what I mean:

[image]

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("title ", values.title);
formData.append("message ", values.message);
if (values.image) {
    formData.append("image", values.image, values.image.name);
}
if (values.selected && values.selected.length > 0) {
    formData.append("selected ", values.selected);
}
if (newDate) {
    formData.append("scheduledDate ", newDate);
}
if (users && users.length > 0) {
    formData.append("users ", users);
}
```

Comment: Include the code where you're trying to get the payload in your node server.

Comment: please include your server side code as well. BTW if you're using something like express are you using body parser middleware ?

Comment: @Muljayan I don't think the issue is in backend, since in postman it is working. Also body parser middleware is added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@SDB_1998 Remove spaces from keys in your code. For Ex. `"title "` should be `"title"`

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("title", values.title);
formData.append("message", values.message);
if (values.image) {
    formData.append("image", values.image, values.image.name);
}
if (values.selected && values.selected.length > 0) {
    formData.append("selected", values.selected);
}
if (newDate) {
    formData.append("scheduledDate", newDate);
}
if (users && users.length > 0) {
    formData.append("users", users);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Darshan Gada for noticing this. I appreciate your help